# Text wont show on textbox (radiobutton)

Tags: java, android

When I click on a radio button, I want its value to show on a textbox.I don't know what wrong with my code, there are no errors, its just that it won't show when I tick on the radio button

This is my class.

```
public class ConRadioSamp extends ActionBarActivity {


EditText txtans;

RadioButton RD1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_con_radio_samp);


}

public void ChkCommand(View v)
{
    txtans = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtcon1);

    if(v.getId()==R.id.chk1 && ((RadioButton)v).isChecked())
    {
        ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2)).setChecked(false);
        ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1)).setChecked(false);
        RD1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);


    }
    else if(v.getId()==R.id.chk2 && ((RadioButton)v).isChecked())
    {
        ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0)).setChecked(false);
        ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2)).setChecked(false);
        RD1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);

    }
    else if(v.getId()==R.id.chk3 && ((RadioButton)v).isChecked())
    {
        ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0)).setChecked(false);
        ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1)).setChecked(false);
        RD1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);

    }

    String value = RD1.getText().toString();
    txtans.setText(value);

}

public void CloseConF(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SampComponents.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.con_radio_samp, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_con_radio_samp,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: taba, where is the click event of your radio button and where to display your text, I cant found it. Can you please paste your full code.

Comment: oh wait let me try adding that >.<

Comment: oh wait, this is my professor's sample, he said we didn't need the on click event

Comment: if you dont need on click vent then you must need onCheckChanged event for the same taba.

Comment: this method: ChkCommand(View V), from where you calling this method.??

Comment: @Taba It is more easy to use `RadioGroup`.

Comment: Ya, agree RadioGroup will be easy to use.

Comment: how do I use a radio group? :)

Comment: do you need full example of radio group with your requirements taba? I can send you.

Comment: I am all good @pratik :) thanks for your help!

Comment: See my answer, it will give some idea, how to declare Radio Group in xml files and then you can use it like piyush said.

Comment: In that xml, all the names are as per mine, so you can change it accordingly.

Comment: @Taba Are you newbie to android?

Comment: yes I am :) I just want to learn this :)

Comment: @Taba OKay nope. If you have any problem any time you can ask.

Comment: @pratik that would be nice! :)

Comment: @pratik into the basics I guess haha :)

Comment: @Taba ALways wel come.

Comment: @pratik I dunno how to chat there haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `RadioGroup`. For that take one `RadiGroup` in your xml file and add `RadioButton` in it how many you want.

```
 RadioGroup rg;
```

After that in your java file just use this way

```
 rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgroup);
```

Now in your `ChkCommand()` method set this way

```
 RadioButton rd1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg
                .getCheckedRadioButtonId());
 String radivalue = rd1.getText().toString();
```

Now set this text to your `EditText`.

```
 txtans.setText(radivalue);
```

Comment: @Taba Your wel come. Glad to help you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

Its your xml with radio group.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="?background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/btnContact"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:checked="true" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/btnDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/btnShare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you got it taba perfectly?

Comment: I think you are newby in android, I mean very fresher in android...right?